# Put exposed form as block back into original view

Tags: 7, views, blocks

I've created a view which essentially is a tag-filter. I have exposed some checkboxes in a form to the user and set that form to be exposed as a block.

However, I can't really see any option to put that exposed form back in to the view itself (as setting it as block removes it). I have the View Field View module, but I am only able to select the "Page" display of the search view, thus recursion.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you are trying to accomplish. Checking the 'expose as block' will expose as a block, unchecking the checkbox will put it back into the view.

Comment: Yeah, it's exposed as a block, but in doing so removes it from the view itself, how do I add that exposed block back into the view? This is my first Drupal project so please don't over-estimate my knowledge!

Comment: Basically it's either one or the other. You could just set the exposed block to also display on the view page which will be the easiest way. There are other ways, but none that I know of that don't require some php.

Comment: I can do PHP, I just can't do Drupal....

Comment: "You could just set the exposed block to also display on the view page which will be the easiest way." You can't do this without turning off "expose form as a block", which is what I need so I can put it on another page also

Comment: Is the view itself a block or page? If it is a page, you can set the exposed block to be visible on the view page in the block display settings. You could also put the exposed block into the view header by enabling the php filter module and adding php to the views header, specifically, the module_invoke function with the correct arguments to get the exposed block.

Comment: The view is a page, and the form is an exposed block.